# Fullcalendar Events Attach Each Other

Tags: fullcalendar

[image]

[Is there a way to attach these two events  each other in same row? I tried with groupId, but it is not working.]

Comment: I don't think so. The calendar just puts them into an order it thinks is most efficient for rendering effectively. https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features if you want to ask for more control over it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up merging these two events and separated the colors by using linear-gradient.